# Replace NA's with a vector

Tags: r, na

I have a matrix 16 columns 366 rows and I want to replace the `NA` with the value of a vector length 16.

All the time I am getting this error:

```
for (i in 1:16) {
  for (j in 1:366) {
    if(is.na(ChSiz(i,j)==TRUE) {

Error: unexpected '{' in: 
"  for (j in 1:366) {
    if(is.na(ChSiz(i,j)==TRUE) {"
>        ChSiz[i,j]<-x[i]
Error in ChSiz[i, j] <- x[i] : object 'j' not found
>     }
Error: unexpected '}' in "    }"
>   }
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

Comment: Try `ChSiz[is.na(ChSiz)] <- x` or something similar. You most likely don't need a loop for this.

Comment: What is `ChSiz`? Is that your matrix? Then you should use `[` instead of `(`. Also, you missing a parenthesis in your `if` statement. Finally, you probably don't need a nested `for` loop here. Please provide example data sets and desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I read, you want to replace the `NA`s in each column of a matrix with a corresponding value of a vector.

Lets say this is your data set and your replacement vector

```
set.seed(1)
(m <- matrix(sample(c(NA, 1), 25, replace = TRUE), ncol = 5))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]   NA    1   NA   NA    1
# [2,]   NA    1   NA    1   NA
# [3,]    1    1    1    1    1
# [4,]    1    1   NA   NA   NA
# [5,]   NA   NA    1    1   NA
(vec <- sample(5))
## [1] 2 1 5 3 4
```

Here's a quite simple vectorized way to replace the `NA`s with corresponding values

```
indx <- is.na(m)
m[indx] <- vec[col(m)][indx]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    2    1    5    3    1
# [2,]    2    1    5    1    4
# [3,]    1    1    1    1    1
# [4,]    1    1    5    3    4
# [5,]    2    1    1    1    4
```

This is basically takes the advantage `is.na` returning a logical matrix that can be used as a subsetting index and the `col` function which converts `vec` to a matrix.